# Routing issue, getting slug in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, slug

I have 2 types of urls in my application:

1. base_url/category1/
2. base_url/category1/categorypage1
3. maybe in the future: base_url/category1/subcategory1/ and
4. base_url/category1/subcategory1/subcategorypage1

In the `web.php` file using this code:

`Route::any('{slug}', 'PageController@show');` I got the `base_url/category1/` type of pages

and by using:
`Route::get("{slug}/{slug2}", "PageController@show")->where('path', '.+');` I got this type of pages:  `base_url/category1/categorypage1`.

I cannot use both of them , because for one of them I got 404. I am looking for a fix to get all of url types in a single controller. How can I do that ?

**[UPDATE]**

If I use in this order , it works:

```
Route::any('{slug}', 'PageController@show');
Route::any("{slug}/{slug2}", "PageController@show");
```

But I'm not so glad to use it like this. I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off don't use `any` since you are going to do **showing** therefore use `get`.

You are probably looking for `?` (optional parameter). You would have known if you read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters) instead of asking here.

```
Route::get('{slug?}/{another?}', 'PageController@show');

show($slug = null, $another = null) {}
// or use Request $request
```

---

> **Note**: do not mix `'` and `"` it looks ridiculous

---

## Search before asking